# How can I reduce the Cache usage of MySQL and raise the free memory?

Tags: mysql, cache, memory-usage

I currently have a virtual server with 12 GB of RAM and 8 CPU running many websites with Apache and MySQL.

When looking in PhpMyAdmin monitor, I see the following resource usage graph:

image -> https://www.astralinternet.com/images/fancybox/screen.png

How can I get the “Cached Memory” to drop from 6.1 to about 2-3Gb and raise the amount of Free Memory?

My current my.cnf config is :

```
[mysqld]
socket                   =/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
innodb_buffer_pool_size  =1G
innodb_log_file_size     =256M    

key_buffer_size          =1G

query_cache_type         =1
query_cache_size         =2M

max_heap_table_size      =24M     
tmp_table_size           =24M     
open_files_limit         =8000    
table_open_cache         =5000    
max_connections          =75      
read_rnd_buffer_size     =4M      
thread_cache_size        =-1      
query_cache_limit        =4M      
max_allowed_packet       =4M      

default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
join_buffer_size=4M
local-infile=0
long_query_time=5
sort_buffer_size=2M
```

Thank you,
Daniel

Comment: ... why do you want free memory? You like paying for memory and not using it? Or you just want a slower database?

Comment: MySQL is crashing with Out of Memory messages. I'm trying to resolve the issue for the long run. The memory must also be shared with a Apache server and Exim, I can't have all memory allocated to MySQL and leave none for the other services.

Comment: If you're getting OOM messages, your server needs more memory.

Comment: You have default-storage-engine=MyISAM and have 1GB allocated to both InnoDB and MyISAM. Do you need 1GB for InnoDB? Also, max_connections=75 seems very low considering your memory definitions.

Comment: On the server, I currently have about 20% innodb and 75% myisam DB. So I have to take them into consideration.

Comment: so Daniel, how did you solved the issue after all this time? Lets us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operating system is using unused RAM as cache. When applications request it, RAM used as cache will be flushed and passed on to to them. This is entirely normal.

[Your system is working as designed you do not need to do anything.](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)